# Django REST: Combine multiple one-field JSON records into a single list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get this result from the view:

```
[
    {
        "person1": 2
    },
    {
        "person1": 3
    }
]
```

But I want to get this as result instead:

```
[
    {
        "person1": [2, 3]
    },
]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do (i.e. what's your end goal)? You can find all of the `person1` values in JavaScript, via `map`: `array.map(function(el) { return el.person1; })` will return `[2, 3]`

Comment: I want to optimize REST responses, since it's redundant to return many JSON objects with the one, same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this method of writing custom render:
http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers
It seems like it's the only method for achieving such thing.